# Is there an equivalent in C# to pack and unpack from Perl?

Tags: c#, binaryfiles, pack

Is there some library who permit to do the same as [pack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) and [unpack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) Perl function?

With a template list as http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html,

pack is for converting a list into a binary representation 
unpack is for converting binary structure into normal Perl variables

To be brief:

I give a byte[] array, a template to parse the packet, and variable that will receive extracted data.

It seems [Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29) is providing such a feature, but templates are not the same, see
http://www.mono-project.com/Mono_DataConvert#Obtaining_Mono.DataConvert.

Comment: **boxing** and **unboxing** of types? it might be worth quickly explainging what the perl version does.

Comment: These type of questions should include some information about what these functions do... I have no idea what these are in perl so wouldn't be able to say if there was anything in C#

Comment: Who the hell voted to close this question? It's completely reasonable.

Comment: @Sayse if I putted the tag perl it's because I need someone who understand perl. I will not explain pack and unpack function because the perl doc take one page to explain it, and copy and paste are useless

Comment: @ChristopheDebove - Not necessarily, if you described the function well enough then those with enough C# knowledge would have been able to participate

Comment: voted to reopen - It sounds like you are looking for [Binary Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72hyey7b.aspx)

Comment: You're looking for serialization: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Vstudio/ms233843.aspx

Comment: @ChristopheDebove Copy and paste aren't useless in that they would provide the necessary context for people unfamiliar with Perl to answer your question without having to poke through perldoc. I agree that it's not exactly a chore to go click past one link but when asking, it's in *your* best interest to make answering the question as easy as possible.

Comment: @sayse it's something like that except I can define whats are the memory segments

Comment: Additionally to what @millimoose has said above, I don't tend to click on links where I don't recognise the address as a safety precaution

Comment: @ChristopheDebove In fact, after actually poking at the documentation, you're not looking for serialization at all, since serialization doesn't let you control the output very much.

Comment: @ChristopheDebove - That link has a [Selective Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/axwwbcs6.aspx) section

Comment: @ChristopheDebove - FYI, I think the short answer is 'no' - you'll need to use ToString() overloads to do pack-like stuff, and Unpack will require Regex's & stuff, I think

Comment: @DaveBish `ToString()` isn't really the right choice here. Perl seems to use strings as byte arrays, not as unicode character arrays.

Comment: @DaveBish I think if there is an implementation it will be throught RegEx as you said

Comment: @ChristopheDebove Anyway, I don't think you're getting something that accepts a format string, you might have to use a `BinaryReader` around a `MemoryStream`. I'd avoid binary serialization because it's really not meant for implementing completely custom over-the-wire protocols.

Comment: You might be better of providing the pattern you intend to use, sample values and the hex dump of the resulting string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that what you want to know about is [Binary Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72hyey7b.aspx). From the link;

> Serialization can be defined as the process of storing the state of an object to a storage 
>   medium. During this process, ***the public and private fields of the object and the name of 
>   the class***, including the assembly containing the class, ***are converted to a stream of bytes***, 
>   which is then written to a data stream. When the object is subsequently deserialized, an 
>   exact clone of the original object is created.

A more concrete example of Binary Serialization for C# (targeting .NET Framework 4.5) can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4abbf6k0.aspx). Brief synopsis; you must annotate the class you wish to serialize and deserialize with a [Serializable] tag, and then use a Formatter instance to actually do the serialization/deserialization.

So in Perl where you can simply say:

```
pack TEMPLATE,LIST
```

In C# you'll need the following:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyObject {
  public int n1 = 0;
  public int n2 = 0;
  public String str = null;
}

// ... And in some other class where you have you application logic

public void pack()
{

    MyObject obj = new MyObject();
    obj.n1 = 1;
    obj.n2 = 24;
    obj.str = "Some String";
    IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    Stream stream = new FileStream("MyFile.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
    formatter.Serialize(stream, obj);
    stream.Close();
}
```

---

To address the idea that you are going to want to control the serialization template, you'll likely need to implement ISerializable yourself. [Here's a MSDN article about custom binary serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty01x675.aspx). By implementing the interface yourself, you gain a very high amount of control of the binary template in exchange for a high amount of complexity in ensuring functionality.

Comment: Not exaclty what I expected but I will deal with it.

Answer (score -1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.tosingle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

The above link shows the methods that are more directly equivalent to pack and unpack.